# How can I trigger an event in Alpine.js once <template> is done populating?

Tags: alpine.js

I'm generating a dropdown of selectable items using Alpine.js' x-for looping  functionality. Once Alpine.js has completed populating the items in the x-for loop, I need to add functionality to each selectable item such that clicking on the item will add an icon to the right of it.

Problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to detect when the x-for loop has completed in all instances (there are three dropdowns in total with variable amounts of items). I tried $nextTick on the  element, but it's firing multiple times, not just when the rendering completes.

I'm not sure how to definitively say that all s have finished populating on the page, especially considering that the three dropdowns have variable amounts of items within.

Am I missing some way of determining when the s have all loaded within Alpine.js, or is there some other way I can go about solving this problem outside of Alpine.js?

Comment: Why don't you add the 'extra functionalities' to the select items during the rendering?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I ended up going with @Dauros' suggestion--it doesn't answer the question per se (how to determine when a template has finished loading), but gave me the extra nudge I needed to go all-in on Alpine.js (I.E., adding the click events in the template directly vs. trying to use outside code to do so). If you're saying it's impossible or sufficiently impractical to determine when the template has loaded outside of Alpine, then that's a good enough answer for me.

Comment: Using the index variable in a for loop you can detect the last element and call a function in an `x-init` directive. However if you are using Alpine.js for-loops then you are already "all-in" at that part of the code.